# Function module RSAQ_REMOTE_QUERY_CALL selection parameters

Tags: c#, sap-dotnet-connector, sap-query

I'm trying to use function module `RSAQ_REMOTE_QUERY_CALL` via the RFC call (.NET Connector 3) but I have a problem with selection parameters. My query has two parameters:

- Material (SP$00001)
- Language Key (SP$00002)

I would like to provide them from my C# program and don't want to use variant at all. When I use variant - the query works just fine, but with parameters, I always get `NO_DATA_SELECTED` exception. I append parameters like this:

```
        var selection = query.GetTable("SELECTION_TABLE");

        selection.Append();

        selection.SetValue("SELNAME", "SP$00001");
        selection.SetValue("KIND", "S");
        selection.SetValue("OPTION", "EQ");
        selection.SetValue("SIGN", "I");
        selection.SetValue("LOW", "Material");

        selection.Append();

        selection.SetValue("SELNAME", "SP$00002");
        selection.SetValue("KIND", "S");
        selection.SetValue("OPTION", "EQ");
        selection.SetValue("SIGN", "I");
        selection.SetValue("LOW", "EN");
```

Is this possible to use selection parameters with this function module?

Comment: In the comment below, you state that you have a problem with multiple selection parameters. In the sample above, you only add one parameter. Could you please extend the sample to show how you add multiple parameters?

Comment: I've extended the example as you requested.

Answer (score 0):

Two things that might help:

- Ensure that you set `KIND` to `S` for select-options only - for parameters, it has to be `P`. Use the function module `RSAQ_REMOTE_QUERY_FIELDLIST` to find out the types (and names as well).
- Try using the internal, single-character language `E` instead of the external language `EN`.